# Getting `UnknownTimeZoneError: 'IST'` while converting pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm executing the following code to convert a pyspark dataframe into pandas dataframe

```
dt = '2022-03-22'
sample_df = spark.sql(f'''select * from orders where order_date = '{dt}' limit 10''')
sample_df.toPandas()
```

but it throws the following error

```
File ~/conda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.pyx:134, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones.maybe_get_tz()

File ~/conda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py:188, in timezone(zone)
    186             fp.close()
    187     else:
--> 188         raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
    190 return _tzinfo_cache[zone]

UnknownTimeZoneError: 'IST'
```

Can anyone please explain what is going on here or provide any resolution?

I can see the result when I don't convert dataframe to pandas, for example `sample_df.show()` works.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two solutions to this problem:

1. **TimeStamp Issue**

It might be `order_date` is of `datetime64` type which cannot be used and supported by pyspark dataframe. The only supported date types in pyspark are `Timestamp` and `Date`. Convert that column to one of them then you can convert it pandas later [1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=date#pyspark.pandas.to_datetime).

For example for `TimeStamp` conversion, you have:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dt = '2022-03-22'
sample_df = spark.sql(f'''select * from orders where order_date = '{dt}' limit 10''')
sample_df = sample_df.withColumn("order_date", F.date_format("order_date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
sample_df.toPandas()
```

For example for `Date` conversion, you have:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dt = '2022-03-22'
sample_df = spark.sql(f'''select * from orders where order_date = '{dt}' limit 10''')
sample_df = sample_df.withColumn("order_date", F.to_date("order_date"))
sample_df.toPandas()
```

2. **Databricks Runtime**

If you are running this on Databricks, try to upgrade the Spark version of your cluster above 3.4.1.